# Read only file common to all Windows systems

Tags: windows, filesystems

I'm working on unit testing a project and want to check that something fails when given a file that cannot be written to.

On Unix, I know there are a number of handy files that can be used to check different cases, e.g. `/dev/full`

Is there some file I can use for windows systems that will always fail when written to?

Comment: For my use case, it seems like the empty path does the case, but I'm still interested in what other ways this can be done.

Comment: Would just creating any read-only file be sufficient? (Didn't know about /dev/full, interesting!)

Answer (score 1):

Load up a command shell and do:

```
attrib C:\path\to\file\here.txt +R
```

to mark a file readonly.

For general info (copied from attrib help):

  `+   Sets an attribute.
  -   Clears an attribute.
  R   Read-only file attribute.
  A   Archive file attribute.
  S   System file attribute.
  H   Hidden file attribute.`